# Django App Implementing Auth0 won't render on iOS devices after logging in

Tags: ios, django, auth0

I have a nice Django app that implements Auth0. It works on all browsers on pcs and on browsers on Android.  When testing on iOS devices however, after the user logs in through Auth0, the device asks to download a file and then downloads it and does nothing. If I try to redirect to my english page, it downloads a file called "en", if I try to redirect to my french version of the page, it downloads a file called "fr". Not sure why - it is at the end of the url myurl.something.org/myForm/en for English for example.

At first I thought the issue had to do with Apple not allowing Same-Site cookies, so I added the CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None setting. But I see now that after logging in, in the address bar there is the url that I want the user to be redirected to.  When I tried using the Web Inspector for Safari on Iphone, I see that there are no same-site cookies, so it seems that this is not the problem. [image: Picture of cookies found using Web Inspector]

I see the document "en" in the list of resources on the Web Inspector when on the login page.  It is type "document" and shows that inside of it is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Sign In with Auth0</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    .bgimg {
    background-image: url('pic.jpg');
}
   
        #myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
           z-index: 1;
    }
   
    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock.auth0-lock-opened .auth0-lock-overlay {
    opacity: 0.0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
           
    .video{
          position:absolute;
      z-index:-5 !important;
    }
   
      .overlay{
    background:#333;
    color: white;
    position:fixed;
   top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
        z-index:1000;
        visibility:hidden;
    /*
    * if you want to make it none clickable but make the
    * clicks go to the video
    */
    pointer-events: none;
}
 
  </style>
</head>
<body background="https://www.nbn.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/auth0_bkg.jpg">          
    <div class="login-container"></div>
 
 
  <!--
 
 <div class ="video">  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.nbn.org.il/source_files/login/nbnommunitywaiting.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.    
       

</video>

  </div>
                 
 -->

 
 

  <!--[if IE 8]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ie8/0.2.5/ie8.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/base64.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.3/lock.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Decode utf8 characters properly
    var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('long_token'))));
    config.extraParams = config.extraParams || {};
    var connection = config.connection;
    var prompt = config.prompt;
    var languageDictionary;
    var language;
   
    if (config.dict && config.dict.signin && config.dict.signin.title) {
      languageDictionary = { title: config.dict.signin.title };
    } else if (typeof config.dict === 'string') {
      language = config.dict;
    }
    var loginHint = config.extraParams.login_hint;
   
    var lock = new Auth0LockPasswordless(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
      auth: {
        redirectUrl: config.callbackURL,
        responseType: (config.internalOptions || {}).response_type ||
          (config.callbackOnLocationHash ? 'token' : 'code'),
        params: config.internalOptions
      },
      /* additional config needed to use custom domains
      configurationBaseUrl: config.clientConfigurationBaseUrl,
      overrides: {
     __tenant: config.auth0Tenant,
     __token_issuer: config.auth0Domain
      }, */
      assetsUrl:  config.assetsUrl,
      allowedConnections: connection ? [connection] : null,
      rememberLastLogin: !prompt,
      language: language,
      languageDictionary: languageDictionary,
      prompt: 'consent',
      theme: {
        logo:'pic.png',
        primaryColor: "#fbaa40",
      },
      closable: false,
      // uncomment if you want small buttons for social providers
      // socialButtonStyle: 'small'
    });

    lock.show();
  </script>
              <div class="overlay">i'm a cool overlayed html block</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and then when I log in and go to the next page, under the Elements, section I get just a blank html body called about:blank.

Here is another image from the Web Inspector of the login page before getting to the first page of my app which may or may not be helpful:
[image: Here it has the "en" document, with the domain that auth0 redirects to.]

Any insight into what might be wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My original thoughts about the issue posted above were completely not the problem.

At some point I realized this:

If I required login through auth0 and passed a context in the view the application downloaded html instead of rendering on iOS devices. If I didn’t require login, passing a context was no problem. If I didn’t pass in a context, requiring login through auth0 was no problem.

Even passing an empty context caused a problem.

### Eventually I figured out that the problem was this:

In the Auth0 Django SDK that I was following, it shows that you should pass in what I thought was an extra dictionary parameter for auth0:
`{'auth0User': auth0user,'userdata': json.dumps(userdata, indent=4) }`

Since I didn't consider the other parameter to be a context, I also added my own context in the return statement of the view like this:
`return render(request, 'mypage.html', context, { 'auth0User': auth0user, 'userdata': json.dumps(userdata, indent=4)} )`
So for some reason this worked on pcs and androids to pass in two contexts, but iOS didn't like it.

Once I combined the two contexts
`return render(request, 'mypage.html', {'contextvar1': 'data', 'contextvar2': 'moredata',  'auth0User': auth0user, 'userdata': json.dumps(userdata, indent=4)} )`
everything works.

If anyone has understanding as to why this worked on other operating systems besides Apple and why this caused iOS devices to download the html, I would love to understand.